# Bootstrap 3 jumbotron carousel with thumbnails

Tags: slider, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm having trouble with creating a carousel slider with thumbnail navigation in Bootstrap 3.

The problem is the carousel-indicators which needs to be inside the container to outline the rest of the content.

The result I'm aiming for is this:
[image: img is fullscreen and navigation gives active slide]

```
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" style="width:100%" data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#7cbf00:#fff/text: " alt="First slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida          at  eget metus.                 Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Second    slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta      gravida     at eget metus.                  Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut   id elit.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" style="width:100%" data-src="" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?